# Spring Boot Migration javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-17

I have migrated an application running Spring Boot 2.7 to Spring Boot 3.1.2. After making the necessary security arrangements, I was able to build and run it without any problems. But when I tried to login with Bearer token, I got `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter` error. I didn't have such a problem when using Spring Boot 2.7.

Here was the one that gave the error:

```
public String generateAccessToken(User user) {
    List<String> roleNames = user.getRoles().stream()
        .map(Role::getRoleType)
        .map(Enum::name)
        .toList();

    return Jwts.builder()
        .setSubject(String.format("%s,%s", user.getId(), user.getEmail()))
        .claim("roles", roleNames)
        .setIssuedAt(new Date())
        .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + jwtExpireDate))
        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtSecret)
        .compact();
  }
```

I have overcome this problem by adding

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

to my pom file and now my project is running. But I am not sure that this is the most effective and correct way to deal with this problem. I would appreciate it if you could share your views on this subject

Comment: are you migrate from jdk 8 to jdk 17 as well?

Comment: Yes, i am migreating my jdk level too